# Django with Docker - Server not starting

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I have followed the steps in the official docker tutorial for getting up and running with django: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

It works fine until I have to run ***docker-compose up***

It doesn't directly give me an error, but it won't run the server either, stopping at this point:

(**Screenshot of the Docker Quickstart Terminal**)

[image]

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: >
      bash -c
        "python3 manage.py migrate
        python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

I am on Windows and have therefore used docker-toolbox.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Your error is right in your post, unapplied migrations...... This is a python issue not a docker issue.

Comment: trying to apply the migrations gives me an 'unknown host' error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start docker-compose in detached mode:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

check your django container id

```
docker ps
```

then log into container:

```
docker exec -it yourDjangoContainerID bash
```

then go to directory where manage.py file is, and type

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: You don't have to exec, you can just run a sidecar container: `docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py migrate`. You should, generally, avoid exec'ing if you can accomplish the same thing with a run; your ops team will thank you.

Comment: I had to do `docker exec -it yourDjangoContainerID sh` instead of bash, on MacOS M1 - if it saves somebody's time.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the migration command into your `docker-compose.yml` file.  Something like

```
web:
  command: >
    bash -c
      "python3 manage.py migrate
      python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

replacing

```
web:
  command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

This will apply migrations every time you do `docker-compose up`.

Comment: applying the migrations doesn't fix it. It still won't run the server :/